# Rails Capybara - Run in AWS instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, amazon-web-services, capybara, case

Is there any way to run Rails - Capybara Integration test features in AWS instance? . AS GUI is not there in the server, how to enable that?.  Do we need to install firefox and all in server?

Comment: You can install an operating system that has a User interface. Ubuntu, Windows? Which instance have you selected?

Comment: we are using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Install `jenkins` for AWS instance, read the installation from [link_1](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2013/5/21/howto-install-setup-jenkins-ci-for-rails-projects), and [link_2](http://gistflow.com/posts/492-jenkins-ci-setup-for-rails-application-from-scratch).
You can use `jenkins` from this [link](http://nepalonrails.tumblr.com/post/14217655627/set-up-jenkins-ci-on-ubuntu-for-painless-rails3-app-ci).

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for your reply. If jenkins is installed the capybara test will run in server?

Comment: yes, all tests (Cucumber, Rspec, Capybara) will run on the server, read more about [jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins)